# Concat series in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few `series` objects in my `list`, wehere every entry contains:

1.number of month (January: 1, Feb:2 ...) as key

2.series object as value

like this

```py
x = [
    {1: AAA    1
        BBB    1
        CCC    1
        DDD    1
    Name: test1, dtype: int64},

    {2: AAA    3
        CCC    2
        EEE    1
    Name: test1, dtype: int64}
]
```

And I would like to join these series to one dataframe which should look like this

```
Index, month, AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE
1      1       1    1    1    1    NaN
2      2       3    NaN  2    NaN  1
```

Comment: read the doc on pandas.concat?

Comment: Each dict has only one Series like in sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested dict comprehension for flatten list of dicts and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last transpose:

```
x = [{1:pd.Series([1,1,1], index=list('abc'))}, {2:pd.Series([2,1], index=list('bc'))}]

print (x)
[{1: a    1
b    1
c    1
dtype: int64}, {2: b    2
c    1
dtype: int64}]
                
df = pd.concat({k: v for y in x for k, v in y.items()}, axis=1).T
print (df)
     a    b    c
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  2.0  1.0
```